# Spotify Web Playback SDK

Tags: javascript, html, ejs, spotify

Hey im following this example from Glitch https://glitch.com/~spotify-web-playback

When i run the example they give on their Glitch site the app runs perfectly. However once i build the app and run it using node (off the localhost) i never reach the Spotify Login page. Just wondering if anyone has the same problems when they try to build the app and where i could be going wrong. I do not change any of the code other than including my own 'ClientId'. The only difference is instead of using index.html i use an index.ejs file as i am calling it from my following server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express()

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {userInput: null, error: null});
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
  })

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Spotify Web Playback SDK Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://sp-bootstrap.global.ssl.fastly.net/8.0.0/sp-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Include the Web Playback SDK -->
    <script src="https://sdk.scdn.co/spotify-player.js"></script>

    <!-- Include our Javascript -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>

  <body class="container">
    <h1 class="text-salmon">Spotify Web Playback SDK Template</h1>
    <h4>This app uses the implicit grant authorization flow to get an access token and initialise the Web Playback SDK. It then uses the Spotify Connect Web API to play a song.</h4>
    <p>If everything is set up properly, you should hear some music!</p>
    <img id="current-track"/>
    <h3 id="current-track-name"></h3>
    <a class="btn btn-salmon btn-lg" href="https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spotify-web-playback">Get started!</a>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
// Get the hash of the url
const hash = window.location.hash
.substring(1)
.split('&')
.reduce(function (initial, item) {
  if (item) {
    var parts = item.split('=');
    initial[parts[0]] = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
  }
  return initial;
}, {});
window.location.hash = '';

// Set token
let _token = hash.access_token;
//console.log("Made it here");
const authEndpoint = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';

// Replace with your app's client ID, redirect URI and desired scopes
const clientId = 'CLIENTID';
const redirectUri = 'https://spotify-web-playback.glitch.me';
const scopes = [
  'streaming',
  'user-read-birthdate',
  'user-read-private',
  'user-modify-playback-state'
];

// If there is no token, redirect to Spotify authorization
if (!_token) {
  window.location = `${authEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join('%20')}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`;
}

// Set up the Web Playback SDK

window.onSpotifyPlayerAPIReady = () => {
  const player = new Spotify.Player({
    name: 'Web Playback SDK Template',
    getOAuthToken: cb => { cb(_token); }
  });

  // Error handling
  player.on('initialization_error', e => console.error(e));
  player.on('authentication_error', e => console.error(e));
  player.on('account_error', e => console.error(e));
  player.on('playback_error', e => console.error(e));

  // Playback status updates
  player.on('player_state_changed', state => {
    console.log(state)
    $('#current-track').attr('src', state.track_window.current_track.album.images[0].url);
    $('#current-track-name').text(state.track_window.current_track.name);
  });

  // Ready
  player.on('ready', data => {
    console.log('Ready with Device ID', data.device_id);

    // Play a track using our new device ID
    play(data.device_id);
  });

  // Connect to the player!
  player.connect();
}

// Play a specified track on the Web Playback SDK's device ID
function play(device_id) {
  $.ajax({
   url: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play?device_id=" + device_id,
   type: "PUT",
   data: '{"uris": ["spotify:track:5ya2gsaIhTkAuWYEMB0nw5"]}',
   beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + _token );},
   success: function(data) { 
     console.log(data)
   }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure I'm way too late to help you with this, but maybe some unfortunate soul in the future still needs an answer...

1. You have to change the **redirectUri** to your own website path in the *script.js* file (line 21).

Then you have to go to your **Spotify Developer Dashboard** to add that link to your app.

2. Go to this link: https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications
3. Select your application -> Edit Settings -> Redirect Uri's
4. Add that same link there